# CASE WHEN equivalent in R for a vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix with two columns, the first of which is sometimes NA, and would like to create a third column that is the value of the first, unless it is NA, in which case it takes the value of the second. I have a for loop so far, but I'm sure there's a MUCH better way to do this in R.

```
matrixA$Age3 <- 1:length(matrixA$Age)
for(i in 1:length(matrixA$Age3))
{
  if(!is.na(matrixA$Age[i]))
  {
    matrixA$Age3[i] = matrixA$Age[i]
  }else
  {
    matrixA$Age3[i] = matrixA$Age2[i]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix$Age3 <- ifelse(!is.na(matrix$Age),matrix$Age,matrix$Age2)
```

Comment: Much nicer than my (now deleted) answer

Answer (score 1):

maybe ,  just for fun,

```
matrix$Age3 <- sapply(1:nrow(matrix), function(j) matrix[j,(2-!is.na(foo[j,1]))])
```

(With apologies to CSGillespie if he had anything like this, since he deleted his)

EDIT:  As eddi properly suggested, here is some expansion and testing of my ideas.  I am now properly and publicly shamed for my incorrect assumption that "ifelse" was a timepig. `switch` is easier to read, but at least for this small dataset and limited set of switches, the time difference is not significant. 
(I may well have fubared the exact cutoff values but the effective operation of these two functions is what matters here).

```
# foo is a 2e4 row by 5 column matrix of runif values 

ifelse4 <- function(foo) ifelse(foo[,1] > 0.8,foo[,2],ifelse(foo[,1] > 0.6,foo[,3],ifelse(foo[,1] > .4 , foo[,4],ifelse(foo[,1] > .2 , foo[,5], foo[,1])))) 

switch4l <- function(foo) {

 for(j in 1:nrow(foo)) {
         switch( ceiling(foo[j,1]*5),
            foo[j,1],
            foo[j,5],
            foo[j,4],
            foo[j,3],
            foo[j,2] )
        }
        }


    microbenchmark(ifelse4(foo),switch4l(foo),times=10)

    Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
  ifelse4(foo) 31.37346 31.87336 32.21567 32.44509 33.21182    10
 switch4l(foo) 28.03629 28.31339 28.61871 28.99588 29.78014    10
```

Comment: Really?  And just what is so horrible about this?  Please at least leave a comment when you downvote.   IMHO this has the advantage of not requiring and `if` or `ifelse`, and is relatively easy to extend to selecting among several columns based on the number of `NA` values.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's advantageous not to have `if` or `ifelse` here?

Comment: @eddi  `ifelse` is certainly much faster for this simple binary choice.  As I suggested, the `sapply` option does have the advantage of being extensible to a large number of replacement options (such as selecting from columns 2 thru N).  Now I'm tempted to write a `switch` version to see how slow that is :-)

Comment: perhaps you can remedy this answer by demonstrating that generalization - as is this answer is just a much slower and more cumbersome version of the accepted one (and more error prone, since you use column numbers)

Comment: Upvoting you for the sheer amount of effort you put into this and also shows an alternate path. Do not feel discouraged and don't take -ve vote too personally :)